# Dynamic AMPscript content on landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page, cloudpage

I've got a small survey landing page built in CloudPages with AMPscript that creates a new record to SF and links it with the Person Account record.

Question is how to make the content dynamic depending on a field value in SF?

The use case is for language field. Depending on the field value, the content is different. Same system fields, but different labels.

Comment: Deleting my answer missed the SF bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basics to get something simple up are pretty straightforward. You would use a combination of [RetrieveSalesforceObjects()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/retrievesalesforceobjects/) and [IF THEN ELSE](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_langauge_elements/)...

Here's an example of AMPScript to interrogate CRM to retrieve the user's language from a custom field, "Language".

```
%%[
    /* Retrieve Rowset of All Accounts for this Contact - should only be one record */
    SET @Accounts = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Account", "Id, PersonContactId, FirstName, LastName, Language__c", "PersonContactId", "=", _subscriberkey)

    /* Check to see if we've located the CRM Record */
    IF ROwCOUNT(@Accounts) > 0 THEN
        SET @Account = ROW(@Accounts,1)
        SET @Language = FIELD(@Account,"Language__c")
    ELSE
        /* Couldn't find the Account in Salesforce */
        REDIRECT("http://some/friendly/error/page")
    ENDIF
]%%

%%[IF @Language == "FR"]%%
    Salut!
%%[ELSEIF @Language == "JP"]%%
    こんにちは
%%[ELSE]%%
    Hi!
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

It'll do the trick, but there's are a few issues with this from a user experience perspective.

1. You'll experience a bit of a delay while the page loads as Marketing Cloud has to make a round trip to CRM (and make an API call to get the language). It may not be worth the extra effort, but I'd consider looking at creating a code resource in Cloud Pages that does the heavy lifting of the API call that's called from AJAX by your landing page. You could then show the user that you're loading the page with a spinner or the likes while they wait.
2. You might not have the language of the user correctly entered in
   CRM. More reliable might be to inspect what the language settings of
   the browser they're using are. You'll get this from the
   "accept-language" header sent to the Cloud Page from the browser.
   You can inspect headers using the [HttpRequestHeader()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/httprequestheader/) AMPScript
   function.

Finally, @Data_kid's answer is very worthwhile noting. If your use case involves sending to Persons/Accounts/Contacts that are established in CRM and you can depend on that data having been replicated to Synchronised Data Extensions, using a Lookup() to go get the language from the Salesforce_Account Data Extension locally would be a very good alternative to RetrieveSalesforceObjects(). You would achieve a faster page load and save yourself hit on your CRM API quota.

Comment: Missed the SF bit

Comment: You're actually not far off, though, if you happen to know that you have all this data in SFMC Data Streamed tables. It'd save the round trip to CRM and a needless use of API quota in CRM. No good for welcome messages, but maybe not a bad idea at all depending on the use case.

Comment: Meh yours answered the OP. Didn't read it well